# Convert Namespace to a single proc

Tags: oop, tcl

I have a set of procs and a namespace as you can see below:

```
namespace eval ::_API { 
    if {[info exists ::_API::API_ids]} { 
        catch {API erase -ids [array names ::_API::API_ids]} 
    } 
    catch {unset API_ids} 
    array set API_ids "" 
} 

proc ::_API::erase { } { 
    foreach id [array names ::_API::API_ids] { 
        if {::_API::API_ids($id) == 0} { 
            continue 
        } 
        if {[catch {API -id $id -redraw 0}] != 0} { 
            set ::_API::API_ids($id) 0 
        } 
    } 
    Redraw ;# I'm not concerned about this part
            # and I'm fairly certain it can be ignored
} 

proc erase { } { 
    ::_API ::erase 
}
```

`::_API::API_ids` is an array that contains points (e.g. `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15`). What the script does is erase points in a table.

I want to convert the namespace `::_API` into a proc so that I can use a GUI button to call the proc. It is currently directly after some other scripts (which map the points in the table) and I want to erase them only when required; i.e. when the button will be pressed.

I already tried running `::_API::erase` directly but it is not working:

```
proc ::_API::erase { } {
foreach id [array names ::_API::API_ids] {
    if {::_API::API_ids($id) == 0} {
        continue
    }
    if {[catch {API -id $id -redraw 0}] != 0} {
        set ::_API::API_ids($id) 0
    }
}
Redraw
}
```

I think that there might be something I'm missing about the namespace. I tried reading the [documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm) but I don't quite understand really how they work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that you really *must* do is use `variable` to declare the variable. For some fairly ugly reasons, failing to do that can cause “fun” with variable resolution to make things happen in ways you don't expect:

```
namespace eval ::_API {
    variable API_ids;   ##### <<<<<<< THIS <<<<<<< #####
    if {[info exists ::_API::API_ids]} { 
        catch {API erase -ids [array names ::_API::API_ids]} 
    } 
    catch {unset API_ids} 
    array set API_ids "" 
}
```

Secondly, you probably ought to actually think in terms of using real OO for this rather than trying to fake it. For example, with TclOO you'd be writing something like:

```
oo::class create APIClass {
    variable ids
    constructor {} {
        array set ids {}
    }
    method erase {} {
        foreach id [array names ids] {
            if {$ids($id) == 0} continue
            if {[catch {
                API -id $id -redraw 0
            }]} {
                set ids($id) 0
            }
        }
        Redraw
    }
    # Allow something to reference the ids variable from the outside world
    method reference {} {
        return [my varname ids]
    }
}
APIClass create _API
# [_API erase] will call the erase method on the _API object
```

This simplifies things quite a bit, and in fact you can think in terms of coupling the drawing and the data management quite a lot closer than I've done above; it's just indicative of what you can do. (I find that it makes stuff a lot simpler when I use objects, as they've got a much stronger sense of lifecycle about them than ordinary namespaces.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is the correct and robust way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

What you mean is you want to convert the namespace initialization code into a procedure. The following example should achieve that.

```
namespace eval ::_API {
}
proc ::_API::initialize {} {
    variable API_ids
    if {[info exists API_ids]} {
        catch {API erase -ids [array names API_ids]}
        unset API_ids
    }
    array set API_ids ""
}

... more definitions ...

::_API::initialize
```

We start by declaring the namespace. Then replicate the original code in a procedure. As there is no point unsetting a non-existent variable, we move unset into the block that only runs if the variable exists.
At the end of the namespace definitions, initialize the namespace by calling its initialization function.

Comment: This answer does not work for me. Had to change the array names to array get to obtain the desired results.